# adding array to an existing array

Tags: arrays, numpy

I perform calculations using 5 fold cross validation. I want to collect all the predictions in one array in order to avoid statistic calculation per fold. I have tried doing it by extending array of predictions by adding array to an existing array. For example:

```
for train_index, test_index in skf:
    fold += 1
    x_train, x_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    rf.fit(x_train, y_train)
    predicted = rf.predict_proba(x_test)
    round_predicted = rf.predict(x_test)
    if fold>1:
        allFolds_pred = np.concatenate((predicted, allFolds_pred), axis=1)
        allFolds_rpred = np.concatenate((round_predicted, allFolds_rpred), axis=1)
        allFolds_y = np.concatenate((y_test, allFolds_y), axis=1)
    else:
        allFolds_pred = predicted
        allFolds_rpred = round_predicted
        allFolds_y = y_test
fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(allFolds_y, llFolds_pred[:,1])
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
cm=confusion_matrix(allFolds_y, allFolds_rpred, labels=[0, 1])
```

Calculate statistics.
However it is not working. What is the best way to proceed? Is there any better way to do the same?

Comment: "It is not working" how? Please elaborate. Van you provide a [mcve]? I don't understand your question.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It worked when I used axis=0 instead of axis=1. I was connecting the wrong dimension.

Comment: If I understand correctly that you solved the problem and it was essentially due to a typo, I suggest deleting this post as it is unlikely to help future readers. If you disagree, you can add an answer of your own.